# Using (await asyncCall()))[0] instead of await asyncCall()

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, rpc

I came across the below Typescript code and want to know why it assigns `myArray` with `(await asyncRPCCall())[0]` as opposed to just doing assignment with `await asyncRPCCall()`. Why put the results in `()` and return the first element? What's the difference?

```
export class myClass {

 static async myFunction(): Promise<void> {

   const myArray: Array<Array<string>> = (await asyncRPCCall())[0]
   console.log(myArray) // returns [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h']]

 }

}
```

Comment: asyncRPCCall is presumably a promise for an array

Comment: It seems like asyncRPCCall returns something like `Promise<string[][][]>`, but we don't have that type information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why it assigns myArray with (await asyncRPCCall())[0] as opposed to just doing assignment with await asyncRPCCall()

Because `asyncRPCCall` is a promise and not a function that return a promise when it is called.

> Why put the results in ()

`asyncRPCCall()` is a promise that resolves to an array.

The expression `(await asyncRPCCall())[0]` awaits the promise, then reads the first member of the array.

`await asyncRPCCall[0]` would try to treat `asyncRPCCall` as an array, read the first value from it, then `await` the promise that that value is. Since `asyncRPCCall`  is a promise and not an array, this would be wrong.

> and return the first element?

The code wants the first member of the array.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely the caller wanted the first element from the async response.

It seems like `asyncRPCCall()` returns an array and the caller just wants the first element.

You could assign the result to a temp array and then get the first element though.